# execve() different program output printing

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, execve

I've recently been working with the `execve()` system call and I've been trying to figure out why it would print the full path of the function I called.

For example, when calling `ls` with `execve` :

`/usr/bin/ls: cannot access 'nofile': No such file or directory`

I mean, if I think about it, it's quite logical. If I call `/usr/bin/ls` as `filename` in `execve`, this is what the pathname actually is.

But why is the `ls` system call output like this :

`ls: cannot access[...]`

and not like mine?

I was wondering if there was any solution to find out the "name" of the program I just called, not to print the full path of the program.

As it's `execve`'s choice and not mine, at least I guess it is, I'm not sure about it.

Thanks.

Comment: On most Linux systems, the `ls` command is in `/bin/ls` not `/usr/bin/ls`. Use also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [whereis(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whereis.1.html) and [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) and [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) in your program

Comment: I mean, does it make a difference in the output? I just saw that calling other programs such as make, cat, grep... does not print the full path but actually just ```Usage: grep [OPTION] ....```. I'm not sure why either.

Comment: That's an error message from the `ls`. How they're formatted or what gets printed may vary from program to program. `execve` can't change that and your question is hardly related to `execve`.

Answer (score 0):

I used of `execvp` function in the following `code` and built it :

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>

void  parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
     while (*line != '\0') {       /* if not the end of line ....... */ 
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0';     /* replace white spaces with 0    */
          *argv++ = line;          /* save the argument position     */
          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && 
                 *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') 
               line++;             /* skip the argument until ...    */
     }
     *argv = '\0';                 /* mark the end of argument list  */
}

void  execute(char **argv)
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
          printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
               printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     else {                                  /* for the parent:      */
          while (wait(&status) != pid)       /* wait for completion  */
               ;
     }
}

void  main(void)
{
     char  line[1024];             /* the input line                 */
     char  *argv[64];              /* the command line argument      */

     while (1) {                   /* repeat until done ....         */
          printf("Shell -> ");     /*   display a prompt             */
          gets(line);              /*   read in the command line     */
          printf("\n");
          parse(line, argv);       /*   parse the line               */
          if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)  /* is it an "exit"?     */
               exit(0);            /*   exit if it is                */
          execute(argv);           /* otherwise, execute the command */
     }
}
```

Now, when i run the program in <kbd>terminal</kbd>, the result is something like this (I tried with `ls` command) :

```
msi@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./output
Shell -> ls

1.txt
2.jpg
Qt-Creator.run
.
.
.
```

It also does worked with this parameter (Full path of `ls` program) :

```
Shell -> /bin/ls
1.txt
2.jpg
Qt-Creator.run
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I actually found the issue and it was something related to the arguments array needed for ```execve``` to work. In the ```pathname``` variable, I gave it ```"/usr/bin/ls"``` which was right, but I was also giving (```/usr/bin/ls```) to the arguments array, which is not wrong, but anything where ls would have had an issue (just like my example), it would've used the first argument in my ```arguments array```, which was here ```/usr/bin/ls``` and not ```ls```. I basically just set my first argument in the array as ```ls```.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, but as It's in an answer to `BattleTested - закалённый в бо`, I figured that answering it here would be better for anyone having this issue.

Basically, to call `execve`, I needed a pathname (here `/usr/bin/ls`), an array of arguments (which contains the program name as first argument, not just the arguments or a NULL array if none) and the environment.

Here for `ls` with the `-l` should've been :

`pathname : "/usr/bin/ls"`

`arguments : {"/usr/bin/ls", "-l", NULL};`

and your environment (NULL terminated).

The thing is, `execve()` will use the first argument of your `arguments array`, which here is `/usr/bin/ls`. Simply modifying it to the program's name, and not path, fixed it.